# Mutual inductance versus self inductance of two parallel thin-film wires

Tags: superconductivity, inductance

I am considering the scenario of two long superconducting thin-film wires (thickness << width << length) running parallel to eachother. They carry a current density that is as usual peaked near the wire edges (see http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v194/n4834/abs/1941167b0.html), flowing in the same direction.

I am looking for a very rough estimate of the value of the mutual inductance $M$ between the two wires compared to the self inductance of one of the wires $L_1=L_2=L$. For example, if the wires have width $W$ and are separated by the same distance $W$, how do $L$ and $M$ compare? Basically, I am looking for a rough estimate of the coupling constant $\kappa$ in $M=\kappa L$ as a function of distance between the wires.

Since I only need a rough estimate, it is likely not necessary to consider the fine details of the current density, perhaps they can be considered to have uniform current.

Comment: Two things: 1) If he wire widths are equal to their separation then my guess is uniform current distribution will be not a good approximation. 2) Whatcha working on? In my job (superconducting qubits) we deal with mutual inductance and capacitance of superconducting structures all the time. Are you in the same field? Something related?

Comment: Yes, in fact I cited one of your papers in my Honour's Thesis. I'm working on flux noise in SQUID qubits as well, on the theory side.

Comment: I know that the approximation will be bad, but I am only looking for a crude estimate. I really have no idea how these would compare, even in the case of thin wires with uniform current.

Comment: If you really want a crude estimate you can pretend you have two infinitely long wires in space. You can look up the inductance and then compute the mutual using basic math and the Bio-Savart law, I think.

Comment: Here's a [treament of the current distribution in a superconducting wire](http://home.physics.wisc.edu/~rfmcdermott/MagSQUIDnotes0211.pdf).

Comment: Thinking about this some more, just pretend the current is uniformly distributed. I think you'll get a pretty reasonable result.